# Read_csv in Pandas where file structure is inconsistent

Tags: python, pandas, opencsv

Having trouble with reading a csv file into a pandas dataframe where the line endings are not standard.

Here is my code:

```
df_feb = pd.read_csv(data_location, sep = ",",nrows = 500, header = None, skipinitialspace = True,encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Here is the output (personal info scratched out):
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAhFz.png)

This is what the input data looks like:
[image: Data]

The above output splits what should be a single line into 4 lines. A new line should start for every phone number (phone number = scratched out bit). 
I am aiming to have each line look like this:
[Goal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxo0x.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please make an effort to post the sample data and expected output. Have you tried `lineterminator='\r'` argument while reading the csv?

Comment: @mad_ I Thank you for your comments. I have made changes and provided info on desired output. 'lineterminator='\r'' did not work - it joined all rows in the set into one.

Answer (score 0):

If the file have format have any rule (not unique format for each record), then I suggest you **write your own convertion tool**.

Here I suggest what the tool should do

- Read file as plain text.
- Put 4 lines into 1 records/class object ( as I see in picture, 4 records seem to have 4 lines)
- Parse the line (split by comma, tab, whatever you have) to get attribute
- Write attribute in another file, split by tab (or comma) => your csv

Now, you can load your csv to Pandas.